# Creating formula for Excel format adding parentheses

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, string-formatting

I have multiple cells that have three values in each cell. What I want to do is be able to add parentheses and a comma for each cell.

So going from this:

```
1.022 0.987 1.034
```

To:

```
1.022 (0.987, 1.034)
```

Is there a way to do this without formatting each cell?

Comment: Will ( be the seventh char always or is it after digit dot digits space?

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", ", ", 2), " ", " (", 1)&")"
```

[image]

The SUBSTITUTE function has an oft discarded, optional parameter to only substitute a particular instance of the substitution's occurrence.

Comment: Nice usage of the 'oft discarded, optional parameter'

Answer (score 2):

Copy/paste this formula into an empty cell next to the cell containing your values:

```
=LEFT(B3,6)&"("&MID(B3,7,5)&","&RIGHT(B3,6)&")"
```

(replace all the instances of `B3` with the correct cell id that actually contains your values)

Comment: You might provide more universality by parsing out the left digits by searching for the position of the first space; e..g. `LEFT(B3, FIND(" ", B3&" "))`. Similar methods can be applied to the other section(s).

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),1*999-998,999)) & " (" & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999)) & ", " & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),3*999-998,999)) & ")"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Throwing another option in the ring. This work provides pattern is exactly as displayed in OP.

```
=LEFT(N8,FIND(" ",N8))&"("&MID(N8,FIND(" ",N8)+1,5)&", "&MID(N8,FIND(" ",N8,FIND(" ",N8)+1)+1,5)&")"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regex?
Requires VBA if that is ok?

```
Function Regex(Cell)
    Dim RE As Object
    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Pattern = "(\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)(\s\d\.\d+)"
    replacement = "$1 ($2,$3)"
    RE.Pattern = Pattern

    Regex = RE.Replace(Cell, replacement)

End Function
```

Use it like: `=Regex(A1)` if the data is in cell A1.

[image]

EDIT; Updated code with the , as pnuts pointed out but did not change the image. The code does include the comma.

Comment: @pnuts I didn't see that. Thanks!